# Kernel Mode Output Cache limitation

Tags: asp.net, caching, iis-7, output-caching

As per the IIS Output Caching documentation,

**"Kernel Mode Output cache does not support modules and features that must run in user mode, such as authentication or authorization. Example: If authentication schemes like Basic or Windows authentication are enabled, the cache policy will not work. "**

What is basic authentication and Authorization in "***If authentication schemes like Basic or Windows authentication are enabled, the cache policy will not work***" statement?

My ASP.NET MVC 3 web application has Forms authentication. Will Kernel mode caching works for my site?

Answer (score 0):

Go to your IIS settings for your website then choose the AUTHENTICATION screen. You should see 'Basic Authentication' there on the list, and most cases I've observed, it is disabled, such as mine, by default. So I don't think there are problems with this, and using Kernel Mode Output, as long as you are not using authentication to access your web app/site.